# Android: reducing code for handling AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm rather new to java development. I'm trying to implement Alert in an Android app with the following code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setMessage("I'm a multi-button alert :-)");
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "KO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
alert.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
alert.show();
```

It runs but I would like to avoid, for every button, the new `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` by pointing to a single function on which handling clicked button. I think this is possible but I don't know how, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can implement the DialogInterface.OnClickListener in the containing class and monitor the `which` parameter to see, which button was clicked.

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", this);
alert.setNegativeButton("No", this);
alert.setNeutralButton("Cancel", this);

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    String text = "";

    switch (which)
    {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            text = "Cancel";
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        text,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach:

```
final Context context = getApplicationContext(); // Should be "final", won't compile otherwise
class MyListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    MyListener() {
    }
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(context, 
                which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE ? "OK" :
                which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE ? "KO" :
                "CANCEL",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        }

}
MyListener listener = new MyListener();

AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setMessage("I'm a multi-button alert :-)");
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", listener);
alert.setPositiveButton("No", listener);
alert.setPositiveButton("Cancel", listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are able to define the onClickListener for its own and add it to the buttons, then you have to determine in the Listener which Button was calling. This do not really reduce the amount of code, but I prefer this way because of better readability (? not sure if this word exists ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Just implement an OnClickListener and set it.

```
class MyActivity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch(which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "KO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CANCEL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
    }
}
```

and then

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", this);
alert.setNegativeButton("No", this);
alert.setNeutralButton("Cancel", this);
```

on the AlertDialog.Builder.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers already, but I thought I'd add another variation:

```
public class MyClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    String mDisplayText;
    Context mCtx;
    public MyClickListener(String displayText, Context ctx){
        mDisplayText = displayText;
        mCtx = ctx;
    }
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, 
            mDisplayText,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    }
}

...

AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setMessage("I'm a multi-button alert :-)");
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new MyClickListener("OK",this));
alert.setNegativeButton("No", new MyClickListener("KO",this));
alert.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new MyClickListener("CANCEL",this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Chris... A TIP I just learned is that you do not need to call getBaseContext or getApplicationContext in an inner class. You can use MyActivity.this as in:

```
    builder.setNegativeButton("Dismiss",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //cancels itself?
           /* Toast.makeText(ConfuseText.this, 
                    "HELLO",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();*/
        }
```

I am going to take your word that you are new to Android development. So first, there are three ways to handle click events. Anonymous inner classes (API 3), implementing onClickListener (API 3) and XML attributes (API 4). IMHO inner classes are more "object oriented" and onClickListener may be easier to read.

Second, consider using the standard Android architecture to display AlertDialogs. This strategy allows the Android OS to handle phone orientation changes for you. It may be more work initially, but it will pay off later. So you would need to read up on onCreateDialog.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_ABOUT:
        // do the work to define the About Dialog
        dialog= getInstanceAlertDialog();
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}

private AlertDialog getInstanceAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Confuse Text JALComputing Copyright 2011");
    AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("About");
    return alert;
}
```

Third, consider keeping the event handlers as close to the AlertDialog code as possible, JUST AS YOU ARE DOING. Just imagine if you decide to support multiple alert dialogs. Unless you have a giant brain, keeping the methods and data close to the "object" is much less prone to error

Comment: Is there any Android design guide about where to define the id parameter of onCreateDialog? Something like a dialogues store. 
On the other hand, IMHO, it is a bad design guide to keep event handler code "close to the object" since a good object design encourages low coupling and high cohesion. For me, the correct way is to create a handler controller class and stick to the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
d.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
});

d.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

d.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ActionAdapter(this,
            R.layout.spinner_row_comman, arraylist_date, builder);

    builder.setTitle("Select days to set Reminder");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (which == 0) {


            } else if (which == 1) {
                dayDate = 2;
                Log.e("dayDate", "++++++++++++++++" + dayDate);

                updateLabel();

            } else if (which == 2) {


            } else if (which == 3) {


            } else if (which == 4) {


            } else if (which == 5) {


            } 
        }

    });

    builder.show();
```